# Access to modbus internal IO on UR driver

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
Is it possible with the two ur packages to access to the internal IO ?
You can access to the physical IO.

Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298204/access-to-modbus-internal-io-on-ur-driver/) by [ThomasSimon](https://answers.ros.org/users/36596/thomassimon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
Can you clarify what you mean by "internal IO" specifically? I'm unfamiliar with that name wrt UR robots. Are you referring to the safety IO, modbus registers, flags or something else?

Also: which controller and which version of Polyscope?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-23**:
Are you referring to the IO ports on the end effector of the arm? Can you tell us which version of the UR driver you're currently using, there are a few out there.

**Comment by [ThomasSimon](https://answers.ros.org/users/36596/thomassimon/) on 2018-07-23**:
I have to access to 7 words of 16 bits as input and same for the output on the modbus registers.
Polyscope 3.5
Controller 3.5.1.10661

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
For future questions: please include that sort of (version) info in your question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it possible with the two ur packages to access to the internal IO ?

If you are referring to `ur_modern_driver` and `ur_driver`, then there is currently no support for accessing any IO elements apart from the standard ones (ie: tool and standard analogue and digital).

Accessing modbus words is not supported.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThomasSimon](https://answers.ros.org/users/36596/thomassimon/) on 2018-07-23**:
Yes, I was referring them. Nobody knows a fork that could do the trick before developing ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
I don't know of any forks that add this.

For writing, you could see whether sending URScript snippets to the `/URScript` topic works. It's not pretty, but could work.

If you do decide to develop something, start from [this fork](https://github.com/Zagitta/ur_modern_driver), and submit a PR! :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:\

> I don't know of any forks that add this.

but that of course doesn't mean that one could not exist.

---

Btw: if you're already using modbus, couldn't you use modbus from your ROS pc to access the words?

**Comment by [ThomasSimon](https://answers.ros.org/users/36596/thomassimon/) on 2018-07-23**:
Thanks for your answer.